# Force Google recaptcha to use simple checkbox click challenge

Tags: recaptcha

I'm wondering if there is a way to customize Google Recaptcha to use only the simple "checkbox click" challenge and not those in which you have to click on various images.

For the first time I have to use this captcha for a website dedicated to senior people and Ive been asked to use the simplest method.

I've looked at the docs but found nothing.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The harder to solve captchas appear if you're using recaptcha a lot.
Generally, low frequency users should only see the checkbox and not need to solve captchas.

> The new API is the next step in this steady evolution. Now, humans can just check the box and in most cases, they’re through the challenge.
>   [Source](https://security.googleblog.com/2014/12/are-you-robot-introducing-no-captcha.html)

As a dev you'll be often confronted by multiple image selections because of the frequency you're solving captchas.

Comment: OK, I'll test that from home to see if I get the checkbox only. Thanks ;)